# ionic mobile app with angular js

Tags: ionic-framework

I added  `<script type="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>` script to my html and same I gave as dependency to my module like `var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic' , 'ngCordova']);`

But I am getting this error

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   starter due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate
>   module ngCordova due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngCordova'
>   is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to
>   load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the
>   dependencies as the second argument.

I am not getting any solution for that

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to give it as `<script type"javascript" src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>`